# Simple linear algebra proof about components of one vector along another vector (matrix elements)

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

We have the linear operator $\mathcal{O}$ acting on an arbitrary vector $\vec{a}$ which can be written in terms of the set of orthonormal basis vectors {$\vec{e_i}$}: $\vec{a} = \sum\limits_i \vec{e_i} a_i$. It is also given that

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O} \vec{e_i} = \sum\limits_j \vec{e_j} O_{ji}
\end{equation}

Now, **show that** $O_{ji} = \vec{e_i} \cdot \mathcal{O}\vec{e_j} $

I can "show" this just substituting into the centered equation above and using the completeness relation., but that is not the same as deriving it from basic relations. How to proceed?

Comment: This does not hold in general; it does if the basis is orthonormal.

Comment: Right, the basis is orthonormal!

Comment: Well, in that case, just taking the inner product of both sides of displayed equation with $e_j$ you get $$e_j \cdot \mathcal O e_i = \sum_k e_j \cdot e_k O_{ki}=O_{ji}$$ since $e_j \cdot e_k=0$ when $k \neq j$ and $e_j \cdot e_j=1$.